# Angular 17.0.9 issue with ng-bootstrap 16

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular17

I have unable to resolve dependency when trying to install "add" ng-bootstrap 16.0.0 to a angular 17 project.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.0.5",
"@angular/common": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/core": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/forms": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/material": "^17.0.5",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.9",
"@angular/router": "^17.0.9",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
"apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.8.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.14.3"
```

}

Comment: Ok so instead of adding with CLI "ng add " I added:
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap":"16.0.0"
Did a npm install instead and it accepts it.

Let me know if any of you do still battle getting ng-bootstrap 16.0.0. to install with Angular Common "^17.0.9"